# How to add the 'checked' status of an input checkbox to be sent through email?

Tags: php, jquery, html, email, checkbox

I'm creating a quote builder contact type of form where the user is able to choose their features, and at the bottom be able to type their name, email and a little message. I am using the base of a simple contact form and using PHPMailer to send the form. I have created a little test page to see if I can get the results I'm looking for before proceeding with the full project.

We are setting the 'value' of the checkbox input as a number so that the quote builder can price everything up so was hoping there would be a simple way of just sending through via email whether a particular checkbox has been checked or not with a name

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="contact">

      <?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
        <div class="panel">
          <ul><li><?php echo implode('</li><li>', $errors); ?></li></ul>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <form action="contact.php" method="post">

        <label>
          Your Name *
          <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off"<?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? 'value="' . e($fields['name']) . '"' : '' ?>>
        </label>
        <label>
          Your email address *
          <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off"<?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? 'value="' . e($fields['email']) . '"' : '' ?>>
        </label>
        <label>
          Example feature
          <input type="checkbox" name="feature" class="option" value="25">
        </label>
        <label>
          Your message *
          <textarea name="message" row="8"<?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?>></textarea>
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Send">

        <p class="muted">* means a required field</p>

      </form>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
  unset($_SESSION['errors']);
  unset($_SESSION['fields']);
?>
```

**Here's part of the PHP:**
Take note where it mentions $m->Body this is where I'll need to echo the checkbox value.

```
$m = new PHPMailer;

$m->isSMTP();
$m->SMTPAuth = true;

$m->Host = 'hosthere';
$m->Username = 'example@example.com';
$m->Password = 'password';
$m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$m->Port = 465;

$m->isHTML();

$m->Subject = 'Contact form submitted';
$m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p> ' . $fields['feature'];

$m->FromName = 'Contact';

$m->AddAddress('example@example.com', 'User Name');

if($m->send()) {
  header('Location: thanks.php');
  die();
} else {
  $errors[] = "Sorry, could not send email. Try again later.";
}
```

Comment: Is this php file where you send email `contact.php` ?

Comment: I think it should be $_POST['name'] not $fields['name']. Right?

Comment: Yeah, it sends from index.php to contact.php.

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn it's using   $fields =  [
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'message' => $_POST['message']
  ];

Comment: I just haven't included that part in the code snippet above

Comment: And I don't see you set $fields['feature'] for $_POST['feature']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p> ' . $fields['feature'];
```

To

```
$feature = "";
if(isset($_POST['feature'])){
   $feature = $_POST['feature'];
}
$m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p> ' . $feature;
```

Comment: Great! It worked, how would I add more than one input field, what would that look like?

Comment: If you do this `$m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p> ' . $feature . " " . $feature2;`, it would be in one line. But if you do this `$m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p> ' . $feature . "<br>" . $feature2;`, there will be line break after `$feature`.

Comment: Don't I need to set the $feature2 in the isset part too?

Comment: Yes you need too. Just change `$_POST['feature']` to the name of the other checkboxes.

Comment: Okay, so I've added this in to add a second checkbox.  $feature = "";
    $featuretwo = "";
    if(isset($_POST['feature'], $_POST['featuretwo'])){
       $feature = $_POST['feature'];
       $feature = $_POST['featuretwo'];
    } and this doesn't seem to work

Comment: No that wont work. Just add another if statement. `$featuretwo = "";
if(isset($_POST['featuretwo'])){
   $featuretwo = $_POST['featuretwo'];
}`

Comment: Okay so now it seems like it's working, but only appears to send one or the other, for example: I now have 2 input checkboxes with the $feature and $featuretwo. If I tick both, it'll send one of the two through, not both. Is there something wrong with the concatenation: $m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p> ' . $feature . " " . $featuretwo;

Comment: It's correct. Is the name of the new checkbox `featuretwo`?

Comment: Yep, missed the spelling. Brilliant, the last functionality I need is radio input fields now, if I have 2 radio input fields with the same name so that the user can only choose one or the other, would that work the same way?

Comment: Yes but you won't need `isset()`. Just `$radio = $_POST['radio']`.